# Need to fetch all span values in a div as an array or string?

Tags: jquery

**I need to fetch all span values in a div into array or string**

```
var tag_text_arr=$("#div_id span").each(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    });
```

Actually i need to fetch all span values inside div and want to create a string like this

span1_val|span2_val|span3_val|span4_val

If this is possible explain me...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that you need them in a string seperated by `|`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should output your required string:

```
var arr = [];
$("#div_id span").each(function(index, elem){
    arr.push("span" +index+ "_" + $(this).text());
});
return arr.join("|");
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HmUUB/**

This will start the numbering at `span0`, not `span1`.  If you want it to start at `span1`, use `+(index + 1)+` instead of `+index+`. [*(example)*](http://jsfiddle.net/HmUUB/1/)

---

If I read your question wrong (and you don't want `spann_` prefixed to each element in the string, you can just use jQuery's `$.map()` function:

```
var tag_text_arr = $.map($("#div_id span"), function(elem, index){
    return $(elem).text();
}).join("|");

return tag_text_arr;
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BQLj6/**

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method to return an array of the text you want, then use `join` to concatenate them.

```
var x = $.map($("span"), function(item) {
    return $(item).text();
}).join("|");

alert(x);
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ewdge/

Answer (score 1):

```
var spanValues = [];
var tag_text_arr=$("#div_id span").each(function(){
    spanValues.push($(this).text());
});
var pipedSpanValues = spanValues.join("|");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = $("span").get().map(el => el.textContent);

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<span>Lorem</span>
<span>ipsum</span>
<span>dolor</span>
<span>sit amet</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final val;

var tag_text_arr=$("#div_id span").each(function(){
        val=val+ $(this).text()  + "|";
    });

alert(val.substring(0,val.length-1));
```

this should do

Comment: @gov: The result should look like: `span1_val|span2_val|span3_val|span4_val`

Comment: @andy , got it , i overlooked , he want span1 , span2 , ohh...got it good catch.

Comment: @andy: I think gov has it right. The way I read the question, "span1_val" is a placeholder for "the value of the first span", not "span1_" prepended to "the value of the first span".

Answer (score 0):

You've already got most of it done.  You can

A. Append $(this).text()'s output to an array and .join() the array with a pipe, or
B. Concatenate $(this).text()'s output + a pipe symbol to a string and then remove the final pipe after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there...

```
var span_text = "";
$("#div_id span").each(function() {
    span_text += $(this).text() + "|";
});
var span_text.substring(0, span_text.length - 1); // remove the trailing | character.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var result = $('#div_id').find('span').map( function(i,e){
  return $(e).text();
})
.get()      // Stop here for an array
.join('|'); // or here for a string
```